# Why is .gitattributes applied only to files added to repo after defining it?

Tags: git, merge

In my repos I'm implementing a new interesting strategy to preserve some versioned files from merges, that makes use of custom merge drivers and .gitattributes. Please take a look:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Merge-Strategies

I noticed though, that if I apply it to files already tracked in repo/branches, it doesn't work. To make it work, I have to either define the paths in .gitattributes before adding the files to the repo/branch, or delete the files and add them again.

Not a big problem, but I'm quite curious of the reason of this behavior. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it is typical to not retroactively apply rules to files already in a repository. The same thing you are seeing here happens with `git` and `mercurial` when you try to ignore files with a certain pattern.

The advantage, as I see it WRT ignoreing files, is that it allows easy overriding the standard rule by adding files by hand that need inclusion.

For changing merge strategies there might be some advantage of changing all files in one go and I am not sure why `git` forces you to delete and re-add the files instead of using some force option to apply this (or maybe there is and I haven't found it in the jungle called git documentation).